# How do I refresh a RecyclerView + PagedListAdapter and scroll to top?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I have a `RecyclerView` that is using a `PagedListAdapter`.  I want to refresh the list (ie fetch the data from my `DataSource`) and scroll to the top automatically.

Here's my RecyclerView:

```xml
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
    val adapter by lazy {
        DiscoveryListAdapter(activity)
    }
```

```
        recyclerView.let {
            it.adapter = adapter
            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
```

Here's my Adapter:

```
class DiscoveryListAdapter() : PagedListAdapter<Discovery, DiscoveryListItemViewHolder>(DiscoveryDiffCallback()) {

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DiscoveryListItemViewHolder {
        //Extension function
        val view = parent.inflate(R.layout.discovery_detail_list_item)
        return DiscoveryListItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: DiscoveryListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let {
            viewHolder.populateFrom(it)
        }
    }

    class DiscoveryDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Discovery>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(one: Discovery, two: Discovery) =
                one == two

        override fun areContentsTheSame(one: Discovery, two: Discovery) =
                one == two
    }
}
```

I'm building the PagedList like so, subscribing to the LiveData object that is returned and calling `submitList` on the adapter:

```
    fun buildLivePagedList(): LiveData<PagedList<Discovery>> {
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(PAGE_SIZE * 2)
                .build()
        val factory = DiscoveryListDataSourceFactory()
        return LivePagedListBuilder(factory, config).build()
    }
```

I am using this line to refresh the list:

```
adapter.currentList?.dataSource?.invalidate()
```

This seems to refresh correctly, but it leaves the list scrolled halfway down.  From there I don't know how to get the recyclerview to return to the top of the list.  I have tried `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` but no dice. No matter what, the list refreshes but does not scroll to the top.  How do I do this?

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in the paging library: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123834703

Comment: Ironically I am having the opposite issue. I would like to refresh the data in the list while keeping the scroll position. Any idea of how you achieved this behavior?

Answer (score 11):

Try using the following code to Scroll to TOP:

```
pagedListAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        if (positionStart == 0) {
            manager.scrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This way is awesome! you saved me hours thanks

Comment: Best solution also to have a workaround to a known bug of paging3 that scroll at bottom of the list on first load

Answer (score 2):

```
class DiscoveryDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Discovery>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(one: Discovery, two: Discovery) = false

    override fun areContentsTheSame(one: Discovery, two: Discovery) = false
}
```

Make your ItemCallback return false.Hope Helps!

Comment: Yeah, it works, looks ugly but it works, otherwise scroll to top doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
    recyclerViewAdapter.currentList?.dataSource?.invalidate()

    recyclerView.postDelayed({
        recyclerView.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)
    }, 400)
```

Comment: I tried adding a delay already, it doesn't work all of the time unfortunately.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in the paging library: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123834703

Answer (score 0):

try `adapter.refresh()`

```
 val movieListAdapter : PagingDataAdapter
    swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
                movieListAdapter.refresh()
                swiperefresh.isRefreshing = false
    }
```